# Getting Roster instead of group list XMPP iOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

I am new to XMPP i have implemented ejabberd. my local host name is 
 `'Orange.local'` there is three user. one is logged in as admin@orange.local from my simmulator and second one mihir@orange.local is from iMessanger.
I am creating one group as

```
@IBAction func CreateGroupBtn(sender: UIButton)
{
     var roomJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString("testRoom@conference.orange.local")
     var roomMemoryStorage = XMPPRoomMemoryStorage()
     var xmppRoom = XMPPRoom(roomStorage: roomMemoryStorage, jid: roomJID, dispatchQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
     xmppRoom.activate(xmppStream())
     xmppRoom.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
     xmppRoom.joinRoomUsingNickname("admin", history: nil);
}

func xmppRoomDidCreate(sender: XMPPRoom!)
{
   println("room created \(sender.description)");
}

func xmppRoomDidJoin(sender: XMPPRoom!) {
        println("romm joined")
        sender.fetchConfigurationForm()
        sender.configureRoomUsingOptions(nil)
        sender.fetchMembersList();

        sender.sendMessageWithBody("null");
        var strInvitedUserName = XMPPJID.jidWithString("mihir@orange.local");
        sender.inviteUser(strInvitedUserName, withMessage: "greetings");

    }
```

Room is created and i am able to chat with mihir@orange.local in group. 
now i want to get all group names of admin@orange.local i mean all groups(rooms) where admin@orange.local is member of group.

i am applying this code to get group list:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() 
 {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var server = "conference.orange.local";
        var id = xmppStream().generateUUID();
        var serverJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString(server)
        var iq = XMPPIQ.iqWithType("get", to: serverJID, elementID: id)
        iq.addAttributeWithName("from", stringValue: "admin@orange.local")
        var query = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("query") as! DDXMLElement;
        query.addAttributeWithName("xmlns", stringValue: "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" )
        iq.addChild(query);
        xmppStream().addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        xmppStream().sendElement(iq);
 }
```

but i am getting rosters response like this:

```
    <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="admin@orange.local" 
     to="admin@orange.local/35441594471443421711351344" 
     id="3F9B0234-0233-4DF0-9174-34CC82FF6B70" type="result">
       <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
        <item subscription="both" jid="mihir@orange.local">
          <group>Buddies</group>
        </item>
        <item subscription="both" jid="kalpesh@orange.local">
        </item>
      </query>
    </iq>
```

and my second question is that when i am fetching all group members it returns empty array Here is code:

```
func xmppRoom(sender: XMPPRoom!, didFetchMembersList items: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("members= \(items)");
    }
```

please help me to get all Groups and members of perticular group.
thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you guide me to setup ejabbered  ?

Comment: Here you can find best tutorial for setup ejabbered. : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958

Comment: I stuck in the same situation. have you got any solution..

Answer (score 0):

Member list in XMPP MUC is not a list of currently available users, it is just one of "access control lists" used by room administrators to distinct room priveleges/roles/affiliations: room owner can grant "member", "administrator", "owner" privelegy to particular JID, ban him with "outcast" affiliation, etc.
You need to track `presence` packets sent to conference jid in order to have actual list of users: `XMPPRoom` interface have `xmppRoomDidJoin` and `xmppRoomDidLeave` methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I noticed that the roster iq that I received was arriving even when I didn't try to query for the rooms list. So I thought maybe it was a timing thing.
When I tried to send the room query with a small delay of 5 seconds, it suddenly worked. So I assume the query needs to be sent after the completion of some setup or connection process.